# Google Docs simulate keyboard

Tags: javascript, google-docs, keypress

I need to simulate keyboard in google docs with using JavaScript to be able print or erase characters on cursor position.
Unfortunately solutions with simulating keypress event didn't work for me. I tried with and without jQuery.
After some investigation I detected that Google Docs have virtual keyboard. Clicks on virtual keys calls this function:

```
C.MOa = function(a) {
  this.dispatchEvent(new Q(Td, {keyCode: a}))
};
```

Where `Td` is a string "action" and `Q` some Event class.
What is the correct way to send this event with java script? Is there other ways to simulate keyboard in Google Docs?

Comment: Just as a note about jQuery event: Events emitted with `$(elm).trigger(yourEvent)` are no real events and do not do real DOM bubbling (at least the last time I looked into jQuery), cause of that those event are only detected by jQuery itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Seems like Google Docs have special iframe to handle keyboard events. Here is it’s contents:

```
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Document content" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: transparent;"></body>
</html>
```

Just dispatch keyboard events to this document to print characters on google doc.

Comment: is there an equivalent to this for google spreadsheets?

Comment: Does this still work after Google Docs' update to canvas based rendering instead of HTML based rendering?

Comment: Doesn't appear to.

Answer (score 12):

Paste the following code in console of google docs.

```
const input = document.querySelector(".docs-texteventtarget-iframe").contentDocument.activeElement;
    
// Insert the character in the document and trigger the save API call
const eventObj = document.createEvent("Event");
eventObj.initEvent("keypress", true, true);
eventObj.keyCode = 105;
input.dispatchEvent(eventObj);
```

You will see the character "i" inserting on the document.

Comment: Does this still work after Google Docs' update to canvas based rendering instead HTML based rendering?

Comment: It doesn't appear to work.