# How to programmatically update Google Docs in real-time (via Chrome Extension or external JS)

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-chrome-extension, google-api, google-docs

I would like to programmatically edit my Google Doc externally via a Google Chrome extension or a simple JavaScript and see the changes live (in real-time) in the Google Doc. When this question came up, I was looking for Chrome Extensions that edit a Google Doc and save the changes programmatically. During my research, I came across [Grammarly](https://www.grammarly.com/). I am impressed by how they manage to apply their spelling corrections to the Google Doc in near real-time. You can reproduce it like this:

1. Install [Grammarly Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/grammarly-for-chrome/kbfnbcaeplbcioakkpcpgfkobkghlhen)

2. Open/create a Google Doc
3. Let Grammarly check your text (words that contain errors are highlighted)
4. Left click on a highlighted word
5. Click on the suggested correction

Grammarly will then update the Google Doc. What I noticed thereby:

- The Google Doc doesn't seem to be updated via the Google Docs API or Google AppScript
- The saving process seems to behave the same as the official autosave mechanism of Google Docs itself when the user manually edits the doc. This can be explained as follows:

  - Autosave indicator is triggered
    [image]
  - Google Docs `save` HTTP request is executed
    The HTTP FormData also contains the appropriate parameter combination (an existing word within the index range `si` (startIndex) and `ei` (endIndex) defined in the 1st command of the array is replaced by the new word in the 2nd command)

```
[{"commands":[{"ty":"ds","si":229,"ei":232}, {"ty":"is","ibi":229,"s":"Test"}]}]
```

[image]

I have already tried the following solutions:

1. Use the [Google Docs API](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate).
   Result: ✓ works but with a noticeable delay of up to 5 seconds

```
gapi.client.docs.documents.batchUpdate({
    documented: <docId>,
    requests: [
        {
            deleteContentRange: {
                range: {
                    startIndex: 1,
                    endIndex: 10,
                },
            },
        },
        {
            insertText: {
                location: {
                    index: 1,
                },
                text: 'Lorem ipsum',
            },
        },
    ],
})
```

2. Use the [Google Script API](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/reference/rest/v1/scripts/run) to execute AppScript function.
   Result: ✓ works but with a noticeable delay of up to 5 seconds

```
// API call
await gapi.client.script.scripts.run({
    scriptId: <scriptId>,
    resource: {
        function: 'myFunction'
    }
})

// AppScript function from Google Script Editor
function myFunction() {
    var body = DocumentApp.openById(<docId>).getBody()
    body.appendParagraph("Lorem ipsum")
}
```

3. Manipulate the DOM directly in the Google Doc (here I tried to edit the text of the Google Doc with JavaScript and then save it).
   Result: ✗ I couldn't find a way to trigger the autosave mechanism
4. Manual execution of the internal Google Docs (auto-) save method.
   Result: ✗ led to an Internal Server Error

Unfortunately, all attempts so far have been unsuccessful or have not delivered the desired result.

Comment: You have used the two options you have for updating google docs.  The Google docs api and app script.  As there is nothing else i dont think this question can be anwsered.

Comment: @DaImTo I'm afraid so. Even though I'm assuming that there must be a rational explanation for why it works faster at Grammarly? There may be a special agreement between Grammarly and Google...

Comment: I think you would have to ask Grammarly.  SO cant tell you that

Comment: Maybe api is not accessed client side in the browser. Detect errors>user clicked highlighted word>Ping to grammerly server> server accesses docs-api

Comment: Yeah, I think your thinking is going in the right direction @TheMaster. I took a closer look at Grammarly's minified client script of the Chrome Extension and it seems that they communicate with their server via WebSockets. I can well imagine that this can improve performance. Nevertheless, I can't explain why Google Docs' `save` function is executed - exactly with the parameters that are responsible for replacing one word with another.

Comment: Have just updated my question to show how the `save` request is executed

Comment: Have you confirmed requests via docs api doesn't trigger save?

Comment: @TheMaster yes I did

Comment: @Druux I'm asking because I remember it used to trigger in sheets - when a edit is made by a script, it'll show "last edit made 5 minutes ago by anonymous" on the top.

Comment: I am not familiar with sheets. Just made another API request to my doc where I inserted a text - "last edit" didn't change. `save` didn't trigger either. History only consists of my changes I manually made in docs. So I doubt it triggers in docs. Btw. are we talking about AppScript or gapi?

Comment: I was talking about Apps script(built-in triggers). There is also another method: where you publish a [tag:google-apps-script-web-application] to act as a custom api receiver (though that would be rare and it's essentially the same as script:run)

Comment: @TheMaster Yeah, I tried that as well. But I am still experiencing a delay of 3 - 5 seconds...

Comment: Does it trigger "save" though?

Comment: If I run it directly in the script editor, it doesn't. Haven't tried the Script API. Do you have any example for me when exactly the `save` function should be triggered? Not sure if that really solves my problem, though.

Comment: I've been trying this as well, I can't figure it out either! Did you ever figure it out?

Answer (score 8):

(This methods works even with new canvas-based rendering)

Turns out it's super easy; we were all overthinking it. You can just simulate a keypress with an event, and use a for loop to instantly replace whatever text you need to modify. However, Google Docs listens to key events using an Iframe with the contents

```html
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body spellcheck="false" role="textbox" aria-label="Document content" contenteditable="true" style="background-color: transparent;"></body>
</html>
```

so we have to trigger the event on the IFrame rather than the document. Also, it wasn't working for me from the content script, so I had to inject another script into the page and use a custom event to tell the injected script to simulate a keypress. You can inject a script as [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9515704/8748307), then, from the injected script, you can simulate keypresses on the document like this:

```js
const keyEvent = document.createEvent('Event')
keyEvent.initEvent('keypress', true, true)
keyEvent.key = KEY // A key like 'a' or 'B' or 'Backspace'
  // You will need to change this line if you want to use other special characters such as the left and right arrows
keyEvent.keyCode = KEY.charCodeAt(0) 
document.querySelector('.docs-texteventtarget-iframe')
  .contentDocument.activeElement
  .dispatchEvent(keyEvent)
```

[(obtained from this answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63595176/8748307).

You can wrap the above code in an event listener in your injected script and dispatch a custom event , with the `detail` as the key name, from your content script, to trigger a keypress [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19312198/8748307).

<strike>For my use case I didn't care where the cursor was, but if you need to find our where the cursor is so you can know how many times to simulate the left/right keys, you can get the index easily by counting the length of all the text classes and finding where the cursor is relative to each character. I found a nice little library for doing this (although, it has caveats as Google Docs apparently only loads one page at a time) that's too long to include here but you can [view it on GitHub](https://github.com/JensPLarsen/ChromeExtension-GoogleDocsUtil/blob/master/googleDocsUtil.js#L183).</strike>

Comment: worked for me too! thanks :) it's important to use 'keypress' instead of 'keydown' even though 'keypress' is deprecated

Comment: Does this still work after Google Docs has switched to canvas-based rendering? @scitronboy

Comment: @HudsonKim It still does!

Answer (score 3):

As already answered here - yes, you need send key events to special iframe, not current document.

I'm searched for same functionality recently. After finding it, i made a library. In further you can use this - `google-docs-utils`.

- GitHub - https://github.com/Amaimersion/google-docs-utils
- NPM - https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-docs-utils

You can use it with Node.js or directly in browser:

- Node.js: npm install google-docs-utils
- Browser: https://unpkg.com/google-docs-utils@latest/dist/iife/index.js

Here is the code which solves your task using `google-docs-utils` package:

```js
GoogleDocsUtils.typeText('test text'); // types at current caret position
GoogleDocsUtils.pressOn.Enter(); // move to new line
GoogleDocsUtils.typeText('another test text');
```

I looked at the source code of Grammarly - it uses same approach as this lib.